# only PART of a spherical mesh not rendering uv texture

Tags: rendering

Newbie trying to create an eyeball. Used a uv sphere, modified it a bit, unwrapped (added seams) and all seemed good in the 3d viewport shading's rendered mode, but in actual render the center of the eyeball is not displaying the texture properly. What am doing wrong? :/

[image: eyeball_driving_me_insane]

Comment: this is really hard to tell from your screenshot. could you upload your file to blendexchange? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: wow that was fast! the file is here: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4536" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4536/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One eye geometry is invisible in the viewport (eye outer), but visible for rendering. Open the [Outliner](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/outliner.html) and pay attention to the little eye and camera icons next to your objects. The eye makes an object appear in the viewport (and in rendered viewport display), the camera activates/deactivates an object for final rendering (F12 or animation rendering).

[image]

To make your *eye inner* geometry fully show in final render, you can either click the camera icon of *eye outer* and make the object disappear, or you can give it a glass shader and let the texture of *eye inner* show through.

In the viewport, you can use the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> to bring back all hidden geometries and objects.

Comment: Thank you so much, and I do feel a bit silly. You saved my eye, thanks again!